# Android/iPhone to have full access of Enterprise Information System?

Tags: android, iphone

We continue to build our fairly small applications on Android, iPhone and other mobile operating systems. This is fine and fun in the beginning of a new era, but when mobile OS matures, gets to be the preferred device for business people in motion, they want something more.

One would guess they want the same access and capability to ERP, MRP, BI-solutions and other reporting systems in there phone, right here, right now. How would we as developers deliver these demands, in a secure yet useful way? Is there today support for this kind of applications given they are not today on the web?

**EDIT:** I understand the fact most EIS-solutions are web based. Still they are behind company gates, heavily garded by Cheif Information Security Officer (CISO) and his/her staff. Thus they are not accessible through the open unsecure internet but insede companies intranet or internal network. To my knowledge, accessing an EIS using an adress like https://www.thecompany.com/eis-solution/ signing in with username/password isn't done today. In the old days, a VPN-solution was one way to access inside EIS-solutions, but will this be done using a mobile device as well?

Comment: Are these "ERP, MRP, BI-solutions" already web-based?

Comment: No (I'll update question). Business solutions not on the web, but inside the companies.

Comment: "not on the web, but inside the companies" are NOT opposites.  Many companies use internal deployment of web applications.  What are **you** talking about?  Please be more specific.

Comment: Not on the web - meaning not a portal with a username/password login. However, I understand multinational companies make use of internet, but not necessary the web (since its different). Internet make use of other protocols than just http or ssh+http (https) which we normally refer to as the web.

Comment: "To my knowledge, accessing an EIS using an adress like https://www.thecompany.com/eis-solution/ signing in with username/password isn't done today."  False.  It's done all the time today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot understand what distinction you are making.  Oracle Financials -- for example -- is a web-based application.  It requires username and password.  It can be run in a "portal".

Most companies (even very small ones) use the Web-based deployment through Virtual Private Networks.

ERP, MRP, Financial and BI applications

1. Are web-based.
2. Are trivially available from mobile devices.

The vendors are starting to include appropriate changes for the small screen.

"business people in motion" have complete access to all web-based applications.  All a company needs to do is (a) purchase or (b) convert their applications to the web.

And Oracle, IBM, CA, HP, SAP and many others have already made many of their applications web-enabled.

Comment: I changed the question once more, to clarify diffrences between web, intranet and internet. Thanx for your patience and reply to my question, which might be my masters degree thesis.

Comment: @BennySkogberg: Gather more data before starting down this path.  Your assumptions are fatally flawed.  I have no idea what basis you have for any of your assertions, but they seem to be completely contra the facts.